# Tagging "regions" in rot.js map generator

Tags: javascript, procedural-generation, roguelikes

I'm working on a small roguelike and I'd like to be able to tag the various "regions" generated via the Map generators so that I can use it as a lookup to environment descriptions.  I see that there are "Rooms" that are generated in the [dungeon generator algorithms](http://ondras.github.io/rot.js/manual/#map/dungeon), however I didn't really see anything similar in say, the cellular automata generator.  Is there a way to leverage the generator in rot.js, or am I stuck with manually determining if I'm in a particular open area (and breaking encapsulation of internal, private variables along the way)?

Basically, I'd like to be able to link up my player's location to the text you see at the bottom of [image: this image], but can't seem to figure out how to do it generically.  I'm fairly certain I could use the 'Rooms' object in the first 2 screenshots, and everything else is a hallway, but I'm not clear on how I could get a particular 'region' in a cellular automata generator (or one of the maze generators, for instance).